# Show own app in list for default browser (C#) Windows10

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I want my application to be displayed under the default browser. I found many many articles for that in the last 3 days. No solutions seems to be right.
Here it should appear:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeqVc.png)

It should work for Windows 10. In the article ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/default-programs?redirectedfrom=MSDN ) is shown which registry entrys should handle this. but it doesn't work. Yes I've read the alert about the way changed how the standard app in win 10 is set but i don't want to set it programmatically, I want my app to be displayed there.
Does anyone have more specific informations for me?

My Code set the registry entries from the article and in the registry, I can see them after using my app. So I won't show my code for adding a registry key here but of course, is there a solution, i will add the code...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me again.
I finally found a solution.
Please forgive me for this code but I didn't found an "officially" documentation for the registry keys. I'm sure in my code are some keys that aren't neccesary but it works so you can test for yourself which keys can leaved out.
The code is a result of ~ 7 days of searching the www

```
        public static void SetDefaultBrowser(string _appName, string _appPath, string _appID, string _appDescription)
    {

        string pfadschluessel = "SOFTWARE\\Clients\\StartMenuInternet\\" + _appName;
        string pfadschluessel_cap = pfadschluessel + "\\Capabilities";
        string pfadschluessel_cap_fileA = pfadschluessel_cap + "\\FileAssociations";
        string pfadschluessel_cap_Startmenu = pfadschluessel_cap + "\\Startmenu";
        string pfadschluessel_cap_URL = pfadschluessel_cap + "\\URLAssociations";
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel).SetValue("", _appName);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel).SetValue("LocalizedString", "@" + _appPath);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap).SetValue("ApplicationDescription", _appDescription);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap).SetValue("ApplicationIcon", _appPath + ",0");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap).SetValue("ApplicationName", _appName);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_fileA).SetValue(".htm", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_fileA).SetValue(".html", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_fileA).SetValue(".shtml", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_fileA).SetValue(".xhtml", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_fileA).SetValue(".xht", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_Startmenu).SetValue("StartMenuInternet", _appName);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_URL).SetValue("ftp", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_URL).SetValue("http", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_URL).SetValue("https", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_URL).SetValue("mailto", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel_cap_URL).SetValue("webcal", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel + "\\DefaultIcon").SetValue("", _appPath + ",0");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel + "\\InstallInfo").SetValue("", "");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel + "\\shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + _appPath + "\"");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\.htm\\OpenWithProgIds").SetValue(_appID, "");
        string PFAD_software_ = "SOFTWARE\\" + _appName;
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities").SetValue("ApplicationDescription", _appDescription);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities").SetValue("ApplicationName", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities").SetValue("ApplicationIcon", _appPath);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\FileAssociations").SetValue(".htm", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\FileAssociations").SetValue(".html", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\FileAssociations").SetValue(".shtml", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\FileAssociations").SetValue(".xhtml", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\FileAssociations").SetValue(".xht", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\Startmenu").SetValue("StartmenuInternet", _appPath);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\UrlAssociations").SetValue("ftp", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\UrlAssociations").SetValue("http", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities\\UrlAssociations").SetValue("https", _appID);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\RegisteredApplications").SetValue(_appName, PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities");
        Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\RegisteredApplications").SetValue(_appName, PFAD_software_ + "\\Capabilities");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID).SetValue("FriendlyTypeName", _appName);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID).SetValue("Editflags", 2);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID + "\\DefaultIcon").SetValue("", _appPath + ",0");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID + "\\shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + _appPath + "\"%1");
        Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\" + _appName + ".exe").SetValue("Path", _appPath);
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(_appID + "\\DefaultIcon").SetValue("", _appPath + ",0");
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(_appID + "\\shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + _appPath + "\"%1");
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(_appID).SetValue("AppUserModelId", _appName);
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(_appID + "\\Application").SetValue("ApplicationDescription", _appDescription);
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(_appID + "\\Application").SetValue("ApplicationName", _appName);
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(_appID + "\\Application").SetValue("ApplicationIcon", _appPath);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel + "\\DefaultIcon").SetValue("", _appPath + ",0");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(pfadschluessel + "\\shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", _appPath);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\RegisteredApplications").SetValue(_appName, pfadschluessel_cap);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID).SetValue("FriendlyTypeName", _appName);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID).SetValue("Editflags", 2);
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID + "\\DefaultIcon").SetValue("", _appPath + ",0");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + _appID + "\\shell\\open\\command").SetValue("", "\"" + _appPath + "\"%1");
        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MDK\\" + _appID + "\\Capabilities").SetValue("ApplicationName", _appName);
    }
```

**_appName** = Your browsername e.g. FooBar Browser

**_appPath** = path to .exe e.g. C:\foobar\foobar.exe

**_appID** = the appID of the software. If you wrote a new console application (classname = Program, Projectname = foobar) then it would be "foobar.Program"

**_appDescription** = A short description, what is it